# Why doesn't FileSystemInfo declare the GetAccessControl method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystems, acl

I am mainly interested in the **design decision** behind this.

**background information:**
[FileSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx) is base class to (and only to) [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx).
Both classes implement `GetAccessControl()`, returning a [FileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) or  [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) object respectively.
`FileSecurity` and `DirectorySecurity` both derive from [FileSystemSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.aspx) - and again are the only classes to do so.
Neither `FileSecurity` nor `DirectorySecurity` seem to declare any methods or properties of their own - apart from constructors.

Yet still, `FileSystemInfo` does not contain a `public FileSystemSecurity GetAccessControl()` method.

**Question**:
Can anybody shed some light onto why `FileSystemInfo` does not contain this method?

**example code**

```
public static void GrantFullControlToBuiltinUsers(this FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo)
{
    FileSystemSecurity acFile;

    if(fileSystemInfo is DirectoryInfo)
        acFile = ((DirectoryInfo) fileSystemInfo).GetAccessControl();
    else
        acFile = ((FileInfo)fileSystemInfo).GetAccessControl();


    acFile.AddAccessRule(
        new FileSystemAccessRule(GetAccountNameBuiltinUsers(),
                                    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                    AccessControlType.Allow));


    if (fileSystemInfo is DirectoryInfo)
        ((DirectoryInfo)fileSystemInfo).SetAccessControl((DirectorySecurity)acFile);
    else
        ((FileInfo)fileSystemInfo).SetAccessControl((FileSecurity)acFile);
}
```

The code is far from beautiful with all the (unnecessary) casts in it and I wondered why the library was designed in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that they wanted to have the two GetAccessControl methods return the proper, concrete types - FileSecurity and DirectorySecurity, respectively. If they inherited from a common GetAccessControl() method, they would be forced to return FileSystemSecurity, and the user would have to cast it manually.

It's an aesthetic choice, mostly.